# Выбрать название коктейля, в котором встречаются все 5 ингредиентов

Tags: sql, база-данных

Мне нужно вывести название коктейлей, в которых присутствуют все 5 самых популярных ингредиентов в БД. Их список я получаю вот так(тут обязательно должно быть 2 крепких алкоголя):

```
    (SELECT `component_id`,`component_name`, count(`component_id`)
        FROM cocktail
        WHERE (`component_typeName`='alkohol' OR `component_typeName`='likier')
        GROUP BY `component_id`
        ORDER BY count(`component_id`) DESC LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
    (SELECT `component_id`,`component_name`, count(`component_id`)
        FROM cocktail
        WHERE (`component_typeName`<>'alkohol' AND `component_typeName`<>'likier')
        GROUP BY `component_id`
        ORDER BY count(`component_id`) DESC LIMIT 3)
```

После выполнения запроса я получаю вот такой ответ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сама структура БД вот такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В коктейлях есть ингредиенты, если у меня 5 ингредиентов в коктейле, то соответственно 5 записей, в которых будет отличаться id и информация о компоненте, если 2 ингредиента, то 2 записи.
Мне нужно как-то вывести название коктейлей, которые будут содержать в себе все 5 ингредиентов одновременно.

Comment: сделайте join вот этого вашего запроса с исходной таблицей по id компонента, сгруппируйте до коктейля и выберите записи (having) где количество равно 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, но попробовал бы так:

```
SELECT `coctail_name`
FROM cocktail one
WHERE 5 = (SELECT SUM(1) as total
           FROM cocktail two
           WHERE `two`.`coctail_name` = `one`.`coctail_name` AND `component_id` IN (4,5,14,27,52)   
           GROUP BY `coctil_name`);
```

Comment: Takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 7 were given

Comment: @paskalnikita вы сделайте подобный запрос к базе данных, если там всё нормально, то значит ошибка в вашем коде на python, потому что данная ошибка именно питоновская (что-то типа ожидается от 2 до 3 параметров, а вы передаете 7)

Comment: Подставил, получаю #1064 - You have ab error in your SQL syntax; check tej manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for tej roght syntax to use near” at line 2 , весь запрос уместил в одну строку

Comment: @paskalnikita я тестил подобный запрос в mysql, не понимаю, в чем проблема. добавьте скриншот запроса, который вы делаете к вашей БД, может быть, вам стоит проверить внимательно все скобочки, кавычки и ";".

Comment: Не знаю как скинуть в коментариях картинку - поэтому вот Вам ссылка на Dropbox:https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qwov05gw1unlwt/5%20comp.png?dl=0

Comment: @paskalnikita попробуй так, как я сейчас подправил. и сделайте именно такие переходы строк, чтобы, если снова ошибка синтаксиса, мы поняли в каком месте.

Comment: нет, увы мне возращет 0 строк

Comment: @paskalnikita выполните отдельно внутренний запрос и скиньте скриншот: SELECT SUM(1) as total FROM cocktail  WHERE `component_id` IN (4,5,14,27,52) GROUP BY `coctil_name`